# SSHFS keeps asking for a password despite ssh key present

Tags: ssh, mount, ssh-keys, sshfs

I have a valid SSH key on my client, and my public key is uploaded on the remote server.

I can login with the SSH key without being prompted for password using SSH, but when I try doing so with SSHFS it keeps asking me for password.

I searched a lot for similar problems, but I still get prompted for a password.

This is what I tried:

1. Used `sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa USER@REMOTE_HOST:/remote_path /local/mountpoint`
2. Reading advice from other similar problems made sure I specify the full explicit path to the local key, using my username and not just `~/.ssh`
3. Made sure I have the following permissions:

```
.ssh directory 700
private key 600
public key 644
```

4. Turned on debug mode - which didn't show me anything.

How can I connect via SSHFS by using a SSH key?

Comment: [Known Issue](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/341)